# Android: How can we backport withEndAction to older versions, with help of Nine Old Androids

Tags: android

I'm working on something which requires about 10 animations to be played one after another, but there are some conditions to be checked at the end of each animation, so I can't use animation set or setStartDelay.

I found it very easy to do on Jelly Bean with new methods on of which is withEndAction while I was doing it as an experiment, but now I've to implement it in an App with minSdk 10.

I'm using Nine Old Android and it works great, but using setListner is very difficult and creates code that is difficult to maintain for 10 consecutive animations.

So I was thinking, creating an Adapter that inherits from nine old androids and I could add withEndAction function which executes the runnable?

Can someone guide me on how to do that, and is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

I used [setListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#setListener%28android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener%29)

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        viewPropertyAnimator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
    } else {
        viewPropertyAnimator.withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: remove the listener in onAnimationEnd() to prevent it to be called again later when you do an animation on the same object

Comment: May as well get rid of the if statement and just use:      ```viewPropertyAnimator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });```

Answer (score 7):

You can now use `ViewCompat` and append any animations you want.

```
ViewCompat.animate(yourView).scaleY(3).withEndAction(yourRunnable).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that I can think of:

1. Create your own animation pool using a facade pattern (this one may be a lot of work)
2. Get the source code from the ADT and modify it. Here is if you can't find it: http://pastebin.com/9nCPC4aR. Copy it (something like `ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat`) in your own package. The class doesn't seem to have much coupling with other Android stuff so should work as it is :)
3. **UPDATE:** here is another option, an animation queue. Similar to the first idea but a bit more straight forward:

Code:

```
public class AnimationQueue extends LinkedList<Animation> implements
    AnimationListener {

private View mView;

public static AnimationQueue ready(Animation... animations) {
    AnimationQueue queue = new AnimationQueue();
    for (Animation animation : animations) {
        queue.add(animation);
    }
    return queue;
}

public AnimationQueue steady(View view) {
    mView = view;
    return this;
}

public void go() {
    Animation animation = poll();
    animation.setAnimationListener(this);
    mView.startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    go();
}

@Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

@Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}

}
```

Usage:

```
AnimationQueue.ready(anim1, anim2, anim3).steady(view).go();
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for help, first one seems really hard to do with what I'm trying to do, I tried second option but it seems to depend on some function in View class of api level 16, would you recommend copying View too or is there any other solution?

Comment: Then, put it inside the package `android.view` on your project. (A bit of a hack but should work) with the modified name to avoid conflicts :) Also, make the constructor public or create a static accessor method.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution Was also using the fantastic nineoldandroids

Instead
of

```
starsBig[4].animate().rotation(3600).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(runnable)
```

I did

```
animate(starsBig[4]).rotationBy(3600).setDuration(2010);
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        starReset(stars[i]);
        starReset(starsBig[i]);
    }
           }
});
```

It worked fine for one animation

Answer (score 0):

I think I have better solution:

```
            view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0);
            //timAnimDelay.purge();
            timAnimDelay.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // on UI thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // here animation
                        }
                    });
                }
            // delay start
            } , 2000);
            timAnimDelay.purge();
```

Comment: No need to use a timer task here... just use `new Handler().postDelayed()`. Either way, this method is probably not as good as Blundell's answer above (it may be possible that the animation takes a bit longer than expected to run, for example if several animations happen at once... if this is the case, then it might be possible that the runnable is executed before the animation is able to finish).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to make your code more readable, you can use the built in [AnimatorListenerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html) to save you from the anonymous inner class mess. You can even abstract it more to make it look like `withEndAction` like this:

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.app.Application;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorListener;
import android.view.View;


public class AnimatorActionListener extends AnimatorListenerAdapter {

public enum ActionType {
    START, END;
}

final private ActionType type;
final private Runnable action;

public AnimatorActionListener(Runnable action, ActionType type) {
    this.action = action;
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    if (type == ActionType.END) {
        action.run();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    if (type == ActionType.START) {
        action.run();
    }
}
}
```

And then the usage becomes:

```
 view.animate()./*...some parameters...*/.setListener(new AnimatorActionListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do stuff
        }
    }, ActionType.END)); // or ActionType.START
```

And for those who must use platform built in functions when there is one(`withStartAction, withEndAction`), simply place the SDK checking code in the `AnimatorActionListener` too to save the client class from clutters.